# AWS Glue for Mongo to Parquet file in S3

Tags: aws-glue

Can we use AWS Glue for the following?

1. Extract data from MongoDB
2. Convert to Parquet file and store the data in S3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this can be done using `"connectionType": "mongodb" as Source` in your Glue ETL job, refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-samples.html) for syntax.

Also [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-mongodb) has below example which read data from mongodb which then can be written to S3 in parquet file format.

```
mongo_uri = "mongodb://<mongo-instanced-ip-address>:27017"


read_mongo_options = {
    "uri": mongo_uri,
    "database": "test",
    "collection": "coll",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "pwd",
    "partitioner": "MongoSamplePartitioner",
    "partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB": "10",
    "partitionerOptions.partitionKey": "_id"}

dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="mongodb",
                                                              connection_options=read_mongo_options)
```

Once you have the data then you write data back to s3 using below statement after doing any transformations that you wanted to perform:

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dynamic_frame,
          connection_type = "s3",
          connection_options = {"path": "s3://glue-parquet/output-dir"},
          format = "parquet")
```

Comment: So, the transformation after getting the dynamic_frame?

Comment: @user1578872 yes after reading into dynamic frame and before writing to s3